# What keyboard shortcut do I use to minimize all Windows when I connect remotely with teamviewer to a Ubuntu 18.04 comptuer?

Tags: shortcuts, minimize

How do I minimize all Windows of Ubuntu 18.04 when I connect remotely by means of Teamviewer to a computer with Ubuntu?

I usually use the keyboard shortcut with Super+D to minimize all windows when I am using the computer locally. But using the shortcut Super+D with this remote connection with Teamviewer  does not minimize windows. What it does though is freezing the remote Teamviewer's connection to Ubuntu and I have to close the connection and connect again to be able to keep on using the remote computer.

Does anyone know how to fix this behaviour?

Thanks